# Pandas new column from indexing list by row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am looking to create a new column in a Pandas data frame with the value of a list filtered by the df row value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0,1,3,2], 'OtherColumn': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

   Index OtherColumn
      0           a
      1           b
      3           c
      2           d

l = [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003]
```

Desired output:

```
  Index OtherColumn  Value
      0           a   -
      1           b   -
      3           c   1003
      2           d   -
```

My code:

```
df.loc[df.OtherColumn == 'c', 'Value'] = l[df.Index]
```

Which returns an error since 'df.Index' is not recognised as a int but as a list (not filter by OtherColumn == 'c').

For R users, I'm looking for:

```
df[OtherColumn == 'c', Value := l[Index]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does your question have a error?  You code for df is different from what is displayed below?  Should index be 0,1,3,2 not 0,1,2,3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert list to numpy array for indexing and then filter by mask in both sides:

```
m = df.OtherColumn == 'c'
df.loc[m, 'Value'] = np.array(l)[df.Index][m]
print (df)
   Index OtherColumn   Value
0      0           a     NaN
1      1           b     NaN
2      3           c  1003.0
3      2           d     NaN
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df.OtherColumn == 'c'
df['Value'] = np.where(m, np.array(l)[df.Index], '-')
print (df)
   Index OtherColumn Value
0      0           a     -
1      1           b     -
2      3           c  1003
3      2           d     -
```

Or:

```
df['value'] = np.where(m, df['Index'].map(dict(enumerate(l))), '-')
```

Comment: Thanks. that works. However, my df.Index has NaN, hence it is a float. Do you know any quick workaround on that? np.array() asks for a int to slice it...

Comment: @AlexSB - If use last version of pandas, then is possible use [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: @AlexSB - for first solution like add last step `df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype("Int64")`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['value']=df['Index'].map(dict(enumerate(l))).where(df['OtherColumn']=='c','-')
print(df)

   Index OtherColumn value
0      0           a     -
1      1           b     -
2      3           c  1003
3      2           d     -
```